how to save and set expire Redis entry with single comand
const { Client, Entity, Schema } = require('redis-om');

const id = await this.repository.save(.....);
await this.repository.expire(id, 10000);

but if server crash or something going wrong and .expire not get executed the record stack with No Limit TTL in Redis.
Is there a way to save and set expire by single command:

The short answer is no. Redis OM for Node.js does not provide a way to save an Entity and to make it volatile at the same time. This is a limitation of Redis itself as there are no commands that allow the setting of a Hash or a JSON document that simultaneously set the expiration.
If you are using Node Redis, you can do this as part of a transaction. But Redis OM does not support transactions.
